# ObjectStateManager error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have controller post action

```
public ActionResult Demographics(string submitButton, DemographicsViewModel model)
{
    switch (submitButton)
    {
        case "Home":
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        case "Next Page":
            using (ProposalRepository proposalRepository = new ProposalRepository())
            {
                model.Proposal.UserID = proposalRepository.GetUserByName(MasterHelper.CurrentUsername).UserID;
                model.Proposal.CustomerID = proposalRepository.GetCustomerByName(model.CustomerName).CustomerID;

                if (model.Proposal.ProposalID != 0)
                {
                    proposalRepository.Update(model.Proposal);
                }
                else
                {
                    proposalRepository.AddProposal(model.Proposal);
                }

                proposalRepository.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("GRQuestions", model.Proposal);
        default:
            return View();
    }
}
```

When I try to update

```
public void Update(Proposal proposal)
{
    mContext.Proposals.ApplyCurrentValues(proposal);
}
```

throw error: **An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of the supplied object match the key values of the object to which changes must be applied.** 

I was looking for a solution and I found this:

```
public ActionResult Demographics(string submitButton, DemographicsViewModel model)
{
    switch (submitButton)
    {
        case "Home":
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        case "Next Page":
            using (ProposalRepository proposalRepository = new ProposalRepository())
            {
                Proposal proposal = proposalRepository.GetById(model.Proposal.ProposalID);

                model.Proposal.UserID = proposalRepository.GetUserByName(MasterHelper.CurrentUsername).UserID;
                model.Proposal.CustomerID = proposalRepository.GetCustomerByName(model.CustomerName).CustomerID;

                if (model.Proposal.ProposalID != 0)
                {
                    proposalRepository.Update(model.Proposal);
                }
                else
                {
                    proposalRepository.AddProposal(model.Proposal);
                }

                proposalRepository.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("GRQuestions", model.Proposal);
        default:
            return View();
    }
}
```

add only one row:

```
Proposal proposal = proposalRepository.GetById(model.Proposal.ProposalID);
```

It works well but I think this is a stupid decision and I believe there is a better way and an explanation???

Answer (score 0):

That is how `ApplyCurrentValues` works. You must load the entity first to use it (= it is used when modifying attached entity). If you don't want to load it first, change your`Update` method to:

```
public void Update(Proposal proposal)
{
    mContext.Proposals.Attach(proposal);
    mContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(proposal, EntityState.Modified);
}
```

Comment: throw : A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship. on 
    mContext.Proposals.Attach(proposal);

Comment: Do you have navigation property to `User` and `Customer` on your `Proposal`? What are they values?

Comment: Do you mean in ModelView.Proposal? on page i have <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Proposal.User.Username, new { @class = "customer_input", @readonly = "readonly" })%>

Comment: That can be the problem. Assign loded user and customer to navigation properties.